# Response from azure search in portal and on Sitecore UI is different

Tags: azure-search

**Environment**: Sitecore 9.0.2 XP0 + SXA 1.8.0 + Azure search

**What I have done**: My data is indexed in the index of `Azure Search`. I have added the `search box` and `search result` with `custom scope` 'locationSearch' on both the search box and the search result renderings.

I have created a rendering for the `search result` to display the field values.

I tried using the word 'test' and the values are getting listed.

Then I tried the word 'Canada' and I got the message configured for no result on my portal. When I copied the query from the log file and tried it in the `azure search` console, I received 2 items in response.

The items received in response has the fields mapped in the renderings.

**Query in the log file**:

> &search=(language_1:(en) AND
>   sxacontent:(/.*canada.*/))&$filter=(latestversion_1 and
>   (path_1/any(t:t eq '89395d52f7e84c37b5d6d027f1815bc5')) and
>   searchable)&queryType=full&$skip=0&$top=20&$count=true

**My question**:

1. Why there is this difference in response on my site and azure
   portal.
2. What is the impact of scope, if I apply scope on both the
       renderings 'Search box' and 'Search result'.

**Edit on 16th April**:
I added one of the scopes to the page item and saved it. Then I removed the scope and saved it again. After this, I was able to get the results on my portal.
I will keep on adding, once I get something.

Comment: What does the content search query look like in your code? Also, have you read the limitations here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-azure-search-overview.html

Comment: @JustinBradley: I am using the inbuilt code provided with SXA. Yes, I have checked those limitations.